# recordset rowcout -1

Tags: asp-classic, recordset

sorry for my english.

i use classic asp and try open recordset with following query

```
 query = "SELECT "+_
                  "op.""ID"","+_
                  "replace(op.""FIO"",'""','\""') AS FIO, "+_
                  "replace(op.""Fax"",'""','\""') AS Fax, "+_
                  "replace(p.""Phone"",'""','\""')AS Phone,  "+_
                  "replace(p.""INN"",'""','\""') AS INN, "+_
                  "replace(v.""ParentID"",'""','\""') AS ParentID, "+_
                  "replace(v.""Name"",'""','\""') AS Name, "+_
                  "replace(v.""ShortName"",'""','\""') AS ShortName, "+_
                  "replace(v.""AddIndex"",'""','\""') AS AddIndex, "+_
                  "replace(v.""StateID"",'""','\""') AS StateID, "+_
                  "replace(coalesce(p.""Address"",op.""LawAddress""),'""','\""') as ""Address"", "+_
                  "replace(coalesce(p.""ZIPCode"",op.""LawZIPCode""),'""','\""') as ""ZIPCode"", "+_
                  "replace(coalesce(p.""Country"",op.""LawCountry""),'""','\""') as ""Country"", "+_
                  "replace(coalesce(p.""Oblast"",op.""LawOblast""),'""','\""') as ""State"", "+_
                  "replace(coalesce(p.""City"",op.""LawCity""),'""','\""') as ""City"", "+_ 
                  "replace(coalesce(p.""Address"",op.""LawAddress""),'""','\""') as ""Street"", "+_
                  "replace(coalesce(p.""House"",op.""LawHouse""),'""','\""') as ""House"", "+_
                  "replace(op.""LawOffice"",'""','\""')  as ""Office"""+_
                 " FROM "+_
                 "   DBO.""LDOrgPartner"" op, "+_
                 "   DBO.""LDPartner"" p, "+_
                 "   DBO.""LDVocabulary"" v "+_
                 " WHERE "+_
                 "   p.""ID""=op.""ID"" AND "+_
                 "   v.""ID""=op.""ID"" AND "+_ 
                 "   v.""ObjectTypeID"" in (19,44) "&wherePart

        response.Write(query)
        Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.PageSize=1000
        rs.Open query, con
```

`where wherePart="AND p."INN" LIKE '%38%'"` all works fine, but if `wherePart=" AND v."ShortName" LIKE '%ооо%'"` recordset rowcount is -1. Executing query with `wherePart=" AND v."ShortName" LIKE '%ооо%'"` in Management studio return 900 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add such line to your code:

```
rs.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
```

The default settings might not allow dynamic traversal, thus "disabling" the paging mechanism.